# Laravel Defender Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, modelagem

Está retornando o seguinte erro da minha atribuição:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$user->attachRole(12);
```

**Observação**: se eu uso dessa forma parametrizei as model do defender funcional normal

```
$user->roles()->attach(12);
```

O que pode ser? Se o `attachRole` não funciona, provavelmente as outras funções do `Defender` não irá funcionar?

Answer (score 0):

Veja bem o seu código, o método `attachRole` espera um objeto e não um número.

```
public function attachRole() {
    if(!$this->hasRole($role->name)) {
        $this->roles()->attach($role);
    }
}
```

O objeto deve conter uma propriedade `name`, veja a linha 51 do código (de acordo com a imagem que você inseriu na perguta).

Portanto, o código `$user->attachRole(12);` faz com que o erro abaixo seja disparado:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Traduzindo, o código está a tentar obter a propriedade `name` de um elemento que não é um objeto.

O método `$user->roles()` devolve um objecto que disponibiliza o método `attach`, por isso funciona:

```
$user->roles()->attach(12);
```

Certamente existe alguma validação dentro do método `attach` que verifica se o valor informado é um objeto, por isso nenhum erro é disparado, mas isso só analizando o código do método.

Comment: Dei uma olhada na documentação do Laravel Defender e fiz algumas alterações

 $user = $this->create($request->all());
        $role = Defender::findRole('Admin');
        $user->attachRole($role);

agora recebo o seguinte erro 
"Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Defender' not found"

revisei toda a instalação e fiz de acordo com a Documentação, não tem erros de instalação!!